# .net のAPIをフックする

Tags: windows, .net, ssl

ある.netアプリケーションのAPIをフックしてSSLで暗号化されている通信の内容を見たいです。
CのWin32 APIを使っているものであれば、`bcrypt.dll`などの関数をdll injectionして書き換えればいいのですが、.net frameworkを使っている場合はどうすればいいのでしょうか?

SSLを見る方法として中間サーバを使う方法もありますが、APIをフックしてやってみたいと考えています。

Windows 10 1709
Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Frameworkでは暗号化処理はほとんど実装されておらず、大抵はWindows APIを呼び出しています。ですのでネイティブアプリケーションと同じ方法でフック可能です。
なおかつ、.NET Frameworkでは全てのDLL読み込みは遅延ロードで実装されているため、関係するメンバー呼び出しがなければDLLは読み込まれていません。ネイティブアプリケーションよりもフックは容易かと思います。
参考までに[SslStreamクラス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx)は[SSPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380493(v=vs.85).aspx)の[Secure Channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380123(v=vs.85).aspx)が提供する[TLS/SSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt808159(v=vs.85).aspx)を使用しています。